# Decomposition of a $(1,1)$ form

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler three-fold and $\phi$ be a Harmonic $(0,2)$-form, then $*(\phi\wedge\bar\phi)$ is a $(1,1)$ form. Hence it can be written as $\bar\partial\alpha+\bar\partial^*\beta+H$ for some $\alpha,\beta$ and a harmonic form $H$. I am trying to find how to write $\alpha,\beta$ and $H$ in terms of $\phi$. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I just wanted to add an observation. Let's say $\omega$ is the Kahler form and $\phi$ is non-trivial, then notice $(\phi\wedge\bar\phi)$ is real and we get
\begin{align*}
\langle*(\phi\wedge\bar\phi),\omega\rangle&=\langle\omega,*(\phi\wedge\bar\phi)\rangle\\
&=*(\omega\wedge\bar\phi\wedge\phi)\\
&=*(*\bar\phi\wedge\phi)\\
&=*(\phi\wedge*\bar\phi)\\
&=|\phi|^2
\end{align*}
I am using that for any $(2,0)$ form $\alpha$ on $(X^3,\omega)$ we have $*\alpha=\alpha\wedge\omega.$